# Stuck again - Need to add another GROUP_CONCAT to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Thank you all for you help on my first attempt

I am trying to add a second group_concat to a query to return data to a VB.Net datagrid. I want to rollup the results of 2 columns into new columns kinda like below:

Existing data

```
Date     Sponsor    Match_no     Team      
--------------------------------------------
1-1-11     Nike        1         Tigers     
1-1-11     Nike        1         Bears
2-1-11     Crisco      2         Llamas
2-1-11     Crisco      2         Tigers 


 Date     Sponsor    Match_no     Tags    
    --------------------------------------------
    1-1-11     Nike        1         Away
    1-1-11     Nike        1         Rained out
    2-1-11     Crisco      2         Home
    2-1-11     Crisco      2         Injury
```

and roll both columns up with GROUP_CONCATs to get a result something like this

```
 Date     Sponsor    Match_no     Teams_playing         Tags
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    1-1-11    Nike         1          Tigers vs Bears       Away, Rained Out
    2-1-11    Crisco       2          Llamas vs Tigers      Home, injury
```

I took someone advice here and created join tables on Team_matches and Matches_tags

Now there is 7 tables :

```
Dates       Sponsors       Match        Team         Tags   matches_tags  team_matches 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Date_id     Sponsor_id     Match_id      Team_id    Tag_id     Match_id      Team_id
Date        Sponsor_name   Match_no     Team_name   Tag_name   Tag_id        Match_id 
             date_id        sponsor_id
```

My query so far is:

```
select d.date, s.sponsor_name, m.match_no,   
group_concat(t.team_name separator ' vs ') Teams_playing, 
group_concat(tg.tag_name separator ' , ') Comments
from matchs m 
inner join matches_teams mte on mte.match_id = m.match_id
inner join matches_tags mta on mta.match_id = m.match_id
inner join team t on t.team_id = mte.team_id
inner join tags tg on tg.tag_id = mta.tag_id
inner join sponsors s on s.sponsor_id = m.sponsor_id
inner join dates d on d.date_id = s.date_id 
group by m.match_id, d.date, s.sponsor_name, m.match_no, tg.tag_id
```

and returns results:

```
date    sponsor      match_no        teams playing    comments
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1-1-11   Nike           1          Bears vs Tigers    Rained out , Rained out 
1-1-11   Nike           1          Bears vs Tigers    Cancelled , Cancelled
1-1-11   Nike           3          Earwigs vs Goombas Away , Away
2-1-11   Crisco         2          Tigers vs Llamas   Away , Away
```

Which is not what im after:

Comment: Wait, what sporting event has Crisco as a sponsor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  d.date, s.sponsor_name, m.match_no,   
        GROUP_CONCAT(t.team_name separator ' vs ') Teams_playing, 
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(tg.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM    matches_tags mta
        JOIN    tags tg
        ON      tg.tag_id = mta.tag_id
        WHERE   mta.match_id = m.match_id
        ) AS comments
FROM    matchs m 
JOIN    matches_teams mte on mte.match_id = m.match_id
JOIN    team t on t.team_id = mte.team_id
JOIN    sponsors s on s.sponsor_id = m.sponsor_id
JOIN    dates d on d.date_id = s.date_id 
GROUP BY
        m.match_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Quassnoi - thats close but its returning the wrong tag   values                                                              1-1-11, Nike, 1, Bears vs Tigers, Rained out, Cancelled, Away, Away
2-1-11, Crisco, 2, Llamas vs Tigers, Rained out, Cancelled, Away, Away
1-1-11, Nike, 3, Earwigs vs Goombas, Rained out, Cancelled, Away, Away
where the tags for match 1 should be "rained out, Cancelled" and match 2 should be "away"

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Quassnoi - thats close but its returning the wrong tag values ----------------------------------------------1-1-11, Nike, 1, Bears vs Tigers, Rained out, Cancelled, Away, Away 2-1-11, Crisco, 2, Llamas vs Tigers, Rained out, Cancelled, Away, Away 1-1-11, Nike, 3, Earwigs vs Goombas, Rained out, Cancelled, Away, Away ----------------------------------------------------where the tags for match 1 should be "rained out, Cancelled" and match 2 should be "away" - sorry about the formatting

Comment: @dMO: sorry, forgot to correlate the subquery. Will have to run extra `1.5` km tomorrow, that's how I punish myself for not correlating the subqueries.